# Scenario to display multiple attributes on the page

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

Begging a pardon in advance for a newbie question.

I'm writing a feature where visitor of the page should see several attributes of an item.

The question is shall I add a separate feature for each attribute or separate scenarios of the same feature or create a single column table in `then` clause listing all attributes that should be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put all of the assertions in the same scenario unless there's a good reason to separate them.  It would take a lot longer to run if it has to get to the page to assert on multiple times.

The decision to use multiple 'Then ...' lines or to use a table is mainly a matter of personal taste as both will work.  Personally if there are only a couple of assertions then I just use multiple Then lines, but if there are more than that I use a table.